# Can Abstract Class Do Work After Child Class Init?

Tags: kotlin

The classes I'm using are more complicated than this but I think this arbitrary example would work just as well. Let's say I have a base abstract class that always wants to multiply one of its Int members, foo, by 2. It doesn't really care what the value is, as long as it's an Int. Also, let's say we don't care when this multiplication happens, as long as it happens around constructor time. Lastly, foo isn't allowed to be passed in as a constructor parameter. It needs to be a class member overridden by a child class.

```
abstract class ExampleClass {
    abstract val foo: Int
    init {
        println("Here is foo times 2!: ${foo * 2}")
    }
}

class ChildClass : ExampleClass() {
    override val foo = 5
}
```

This won't work, obviously. Parent classes get constructed first so an error would be thrown at runtime because the member wouldn't be instantiated yet. But with my conditions, I don't mind if the work with foo happens after the child class gets instantiated. **Is there a way for the parent class to say "do this once my child is done instantiating"?** Or do I just need to concede to the compromise:

```
abstract class ExampleClass {
    abstract val foo: Int
    fun bar() {
        println("Here is foo times 2!: ${foo * 2}")
    }
}

class ChildClass : ExampleClass() {
    override val foo = 5
    init {
       bar()
    }
}
```

And have all my child classes call `bar()` on init? It feels wrong to do it this way since the work done with foo would only happen once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no, this is not possible.

The Kotlin language [documentation for class initialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order) says this:

> [B]y the time of the base class constructor execution, the properties declared or overridden in the derived class are not yet initialized. If any of those properties are used in the base class initialization logic (either directly or indirectly, through another overridden open member implementation), it may lead to incorrect behavior or a runtime failure. When designing a base class, you should therefore avoid using open members in the constructors, property initializers, and init blocks.

An `abstract` property is inherently `open`, so the recommendation here applies to your case as well: design your classes to avoid this.

Additionally, I can't find any callback-style method or any other way to "hook in" to the class initialization logic/flow and say "do `foo()` after initialization is complete".

Comment: I suspected this was the case, otherwise I this sort of question would've been asked and answered in some other post already. I must admit though, I've gotten so used to Kotlin seemingly being able to do whatever I want I'm a little surprised that it couldn't do this! That's fine though, I'm only writing a few more lines of code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible, if you use a getter in your child class.

```
abstract class ExampleClass {
    abstract val foo: Int
    init {
        println("Here is foo times 2!: ${foo * 2}")
    }
}

class ChildClass : ExampleClass() {
    override val foo
    get() = 5
}

fun main() {
    val test = ChildClass()
}
```

Have a try [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) and with a mutable [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: Haha I appreciate the cleverness! But there's two problems with this answer in my opinion: 1. The getter approach still seems like a hack that would have inconsistent behavior depending on the implementation (unless there's something that you can point to that would say otherwise) and 2. A getter method works for simple/small classes and types, like the Int member in my example, but this approach wouldn't work with non-static members that I need a consistent reference to. For example, if instead foo was a `MutableList<Int>` that was subject to changes, this method would fall apart.

Comment: Still possible, if you create another mutable variable that you get with foo.
But that variable need to be nullable and your getter must give a default value.
In that case, bettter for your getter to send a list instead of a mutable.
I agree that's still an hack.

Comment: Oh okay, that's pretty clever. I wish I could say I recommend it.